# Download AL symbols not found error, how to change my connection url?

Tags: visual-studio-code, dynamics-business-central

Why my Visual Studio is connecting to `http://adrianbc/BC/dev/metadata?tenant=default`?

I'm able to connect by browser to Business Central:
[image]

When I try to **download AL symbols** I get **Not Found** error:

```
[2022-02-11 13:20:58.02] Using reference symbols cache path: c:\Users\dimitri\OneDriveArqui\AL\Pan\./.alpackages
[2022-02-11 13:20:58.02] Sending request to http://adrianbc/BC/dev/metadata?tenant=default
[2022-02-11 13:20:58.03] The request for path /BC/dev/metadata?tenant=default failed with code NotFound. Reason: Not Found
[2022-02-11 13:20:58.03] Sending request to http://adrianbc/BC/dev/webendpoint
[2022-02-11 13:20:58.03] The request for path /BC/dev/webendpoint failed with code NotFound. Reason: Not Found
[2022-02-11 13:20:58.03] Sending request to http://adrianbc/BC/dev/metadata?tenant=default
[2022-02-11 13:20:58.03] The request for path /BC/dev/metadata?tenant=default failed with code NotFound. Reason: Not Found
[2022-02-11 13:20:58.03] Sending request to http://adrianbc/BC/dev/webendpoint
[2022-02-11 13:20:58.04] The request for path /BC/dev/webendpoint failed with code NotFound. Reason: Not Found
[2022-02-11 13:20:58.04] Sending request to http://adrianbc/BC/dev/metadata?tenant=default
[2022-02-11 13:20:58.04] The request for path /BC/dev/metadata?tenant=default failed with code NotFound. Reason: Not Found
[2022-02-11 13:20:58.04] Sending request to http://adrianbc/BC/dev/webendpoint
[2022-02-11 13:20:58.04] The request for path /BC/dev/webendpoint failed with code NotFound. Reason: Not Found
```

Here is my **launch.json**:

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [        
    {
        "type": "al",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "AdrianBC local",
        "server": "http://AdrianBC",
        "port": 80,
        "serverInstance": "BC",
        "authentication": "UserPassword",
        "breakOnError": true,
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "enableLongRunningSqlStatements": true,
        "enableSqlInformationDebugger": true,
        "tenant": "default",
        "schemaUpdateMode": "Synchronize"
    }
]}
```

Here is my **docker setup**:

```
Mounting Tenant
Mounting Database for default on server localhost\SQLEXPRESS with AllowAppDatabaseWrite = False
Sync'ing Tenant
Tenant is Operational
Creating http download site
Setting SA Password and enabling SA
Creating adrian as SQL User and add to sysadmin
Creating SUPER user
Container IP Address: 172.24.103.254
Container Hostname  : AdrianBC
Container Dns Name  : AdrianBC
Web Client          : http://AdrianBC/BC/?tenant=default
Dev. Server         : http://AdrianBC
Dev. ServerInstance : BC
Dev. Server Tenant  : default
Setting AdrianBC to 172.24.103.254 in host hosts file
Setting AdrianBC-default to 172.24.103.254 in host hosts file
Setting AdrianBC-default to 172.24.103.254 in container hosts file

Files:
http://AdrianBC:8080/ALLanguage.vsix

Container Total Physical Memory is 8.5Gb
Container Free Physical Memory is 5.8Gb

Initialization took 38 seconds
Ready for connections!
Reading CustomSettings.config from AdrianBC
Creating Desktop Shortcuts for AdrianBC
Container AdrianBC successfully created

Use:
Get-BcContainerEventLog -containerName AdrianBC to retrieve a snapshot of the event log from the container
Get-BcContainerDebugInfo -containerName AdrianBC to get debug information about the container
Enter-BcContainer -containerName AdrianBC to open a PowerShell prompt inside the container
Remove-BcContainer -containerName AdrianBC to remove the container again
docker logs AdrianBC to retrieve information about URL's again

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

This is how I've created the docker in PowerShell:

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName $("Microsoft-Hyper-V", "Containers") -All

Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted

Import-Module PowerShellGet

Install-Module -Name BcContainerHelper

$artifactUrl = Get-BCArtifactUrl -version 19 -country es  -type Sandbox

New-BCContainer -accept_eula -accept_outdated -containerName AdrianBC -artifactUrl $artifactUrl -shortcuts DesktopFolder -updateHosts -isolation hyperv -doNotExportObjectsToText -restart no -auth UserPassword -Verbose -locale "es-ES"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your port is wrong. With default settings that can be left blank.

You can setup the ports on your business central service tiers manually. When you change the development port you will need to change it in your launch.json.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/business-central/dev-itpro/administration/configure-web-server